# Taking snapshot of a QML view

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, snapshot, application-design

I want to take the snapshot of a QML view and save it somewhere on the disk.

Is this possible?

For simplicity, assume the view is a Calendar

```
    Calendar
    {
        id: calendar
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is quite easy:

```
calendar.grabToImage(function(result) { result.saveToFile("something.png") });
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The important part here is not the content of your QML view but how you load it? Do you use a `QQuickWindow` (or some similar class) or do you use the `QQmlApplicationEngine` to do that?

- `QQuickWindow`/`QQuickView` etc. - it has the [`grabWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#grabWindow) function which returns a `QImage` of what it contains
- `QQmlApplicationEngine` - you need to find the root object that can be cast to `QQuickWindow` and then do as above.

  ```
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
  // Usually the top level object is your window so you can
  // omit the loop below and go straight for 
  // engine.rootObjects()[0] but it's still wise to check the 
  // result from the casting

  foreach(QObject* obj, engine.rootObjects()) {
    QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(obj);
    if (window) {
      QImage image = window->grabWindow();
      qDebug() << image;
    }
  }
  ```

Once you get the `QImage` you can [convert it to `QPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#convertFromImage) and store it as a file.

Since you have your view `Calendar` you can work directly with it and there is no need to "search" for it among the other objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But since I'm using QQmlApplicationEngine so when the item I want to grab is not the root item I'll have to search for it.  The solution provided by @dtech is better in my case because that way I can do everything from within QML.

Comment: I didn't know you can `grabImage()` from within QML so it definitely something new for me too.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to take a snapshot of an item with [`Item::grabToImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) from QML, or with [`QQuickItem::grabToImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#grabToImage) from C++. There's also [`QQuickWindow::grabImage()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#grabWindow) for taking a snapshot of the whole window.